# Is there a package in Java for mapping a JSON payload like below to a corresponding list of objects

Tags: json

Suppose you have a class defined as below:

```
class Clazz {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

I need to map the following json payload to a list of objects of class Clazz

```
{
    "keys": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "values": [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]
    ]
}
```

The above payload will get mapped to three objects:

```
Clazz(a=1, b=2, c=3),
Clazz(a=4, b=5, c=6),
Clazz(a=7, b=8, c=9)
```

Is there any standardized package in Java that would let me do this? Or is looping through and mapping it one by one the best way to do it?